# Create EXE, which executes file inside its

Tags: windows, windows-10

I want to create an EXE file for Windows 10, which can execute a file inside it
Just like this:
I have HTA file - (file.hta)
And I want to have EXE, which does include the file.hta, and when clicked, will execute the file file.hta

Answer (score 0):

See  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979305/compiling-hta-file-to-exe)  on stackoverflow.

Look for the VBSedit and HTAEdit entries.

Excerpt from the post:

"HTAEdit, which comes bundled with [VBSedit](https://www.vbsedit.com/), ... extracts the original hta file to a subdirectory in %temp% and passes it off to mshta.exe to execute"

Good luck.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Done @DavidPostill.. I should have done that to begin with.  Let me know if it still isn't good enough :)

Comment: Hi, actually when I put my code into VBSEdit it instantly crashes.

Comment: I don't know why that might happen to you.  I just installed it and used [this](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/software_hta.txt) hta as an example.  I compiled it into an exe and it runs fine.  I don't know why you might be crashing.